# Python notification on Windows platform

Tags: python-2.7

I am running this code on Windows 10:

```
import os
os.system("notify-send 'Hey' 'Result Declared'")
```

But it's not working and telling:

> 'notify-send' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

What do I have to do?

Comment: What gave you the idea to use `notify-send` in the first place?! Isn't it a *NIX command?

Answer (score 1):

`notify-send` is not a Windows command. Try [msg.exe](http://ss64.com/nt/msg.html).

Answer (score 0):

iPhone/iPad/smartphones/smart pads/etc
Have the same Python values and the way you do it is

```
From notification import schedule 
Schedule(message)
```

And then you have it.